# Plotting (x,y, z axes)

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I have some problems with this. I need to plot x, y and z axes, and then, this 3d figure. On the Net I did not find something similar (examples etc.). I need some hints or links that can help me with this task.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `tikz-3dplot` you could do the following.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{105} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line join=round,>=stealth,
bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (6,0,0) coordinate(X) node[pos=1.05] {$x$};
 \draw[->]  (O) -- (0,4,0) coordinate(Y) node[pos=1.05] {$y$};
 \draw[->]  (O) -- (0,0,4) coordinate(Z) node[pos=1.05] {$z$};
 \draw (4,0,0) coordinate(A) node[bullet,label=below right:$A$,label=left:$m$]{}
  -- (4,0,2) coordinate(D) node[bullet,label=left:$D$]{} 
  -- (0,0,2) coordinate(C) node[bullet,label=left:$C$]{} node[pos=0.75,bullet] (CD){}
  -- (0,3,2) coordinate(E) node[bullet,label=right:$E$]{}
  -- (D) node[pos=0.25,bullet] (ED){} ;
 \draw[densely dotted] (C) -- (A) node[pos=0.25,bullet] (CA){};
 \draw[thick] (E) -- (A) node[pos=0.25,bullet] (EA){};
 \draw[densely dotted] (CD) -- (CA) -- (EA);
 \draw (CD) -- (ED) -- (EA);
 \draw[dotted] (CA) -- (1,0,0) node[left]{$i$} (E) -- (0,3,0)  node[below right]{$m$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `intersections` library of Ti*K*z, you could get this.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}  
    \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (-135:5);
    \coordinate (E) at (4,1.5);
    \coordinate (s) at (0,1.5);
    \draw [->] (O)--++(-135:6)node[right]{$x$};
    \draw [->] (O)--++(0:5)node[right]{$y$};
    \draw [->] (O)--++(90:3)node[right]{$z$};
\path [draw, ultra thick, name path=AE] (A)node[right=1mm]{$A$}--(E)node[right]{$E$};
\draw (s)node[above right=1mm]{$C$}--(E);
\draw (A)--++(90:1.5)coordinate(D);
\path [draw,name path=DE] (D)--(E);
\path [draw,name path=Ds] (D)node[above left]{$D$}--(s);
\path [draw,densely dotted,name path=As](A)--(s)node[left]{$s$};
\path [name path=ls](-0.75,4)--(-0.75,-4);
\path [name path=rs](2.5,4)--(2.5,-4);
\path [name intersections={of=ls and Ds, by={1}}];
\path [name intersections={of=ls and As, by={2}}];
\path [name intersections={of=rs and DE, by={3}}];
\path [name intersections={of=rs and AE, by={4}}];
\draw (2)--(1)--(3)--(4);
\draw [densely dotted] (2)--(4);
\foreach \t in {1,2,3,4,A,E,s,O,D}{
\filldraw (\t) circle (1.5pt);}
\draw [densely dotted](E)--(4,0)node [below]{$n$};
\draw[densely dotted] (2)--++(-90:1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]